# How to run a Phantomjs server with an upstart script?

Tags: bash, scripts, upstart, nodejs

I have `phantomjs` installed and I want to run a phantom server whenever the (Ubuntu) server starts.

I am currently working locally on Ubuntu 14.04, and the server this will be deployed to is also Ubuntu 14.04.

This is what I have so far:

upstart script:

```
# /etc/init/phantomjs.conf

start on startup

exec '/path/to/script/to/start/server.bash'
```

bash script to start the phantom server:

```
#/path/to/script/to/start/server.bash   

#!/bin/bash

phantomjs /path/to/the/server.js -host 127.0.0.1 -port 1337
```

When I run the server normally from the command line, it works as expected.

When I run the upstart script, it ouputs `OK, PhantomJS is ready` to the log file, but when I make post requests to it, nothing else happens.  I would expect it to output something to the log each time I make a request, like it does when I run it from the command line, but it seems to just start the server and then nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the reason this wasn't working was because the phantomjs server only works properly if I start the server in the directory the file is in.

Executing the full path of the script doesn't work.

To fix this I took Stef K's script and added

```
evn SERVER_DER=/path/to/server/directory
evn SERVER_FILE=phantomserver.js
...
script
    chdir $SERVER_DIR
    exec phantomjs $SERVER_FILE -host $HOST -port $PORT | logger -s -t "phantomjs: "
end script
```

Thank you Stef K and CameronNemo for your improved versions of my initial script.

Comment: **Warning**: Upstart scripts run as root. Have a look at http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#setuid on changing that.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the `console log` stanza to have the logs stored in /var/log/upstart. console log is actually the default, so they should appear there with this job automatically:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn

exec phantomjs /path/to/the/server.js -host 127.0.0.1 -port 1337
```

I did not reset the respawn limti, as the one that Stef used is a little aggressive and could result in Upstart thrashing the respawn (doing it constantly even though it is probably best to just give up).

Answer (score 1):

Save the following job at `/etc/init/` as `myphantomjs.conf`

```
description 'phantomjs'
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]
respawn
# in case of failure retry 3 times to respawn with 5 sec interval
respawn limit 3 5

# set some variables
env SERVER=/path/to/the/server.js
env HOST=127.0.0.1
env PORT=1337

# enable logger output and write to syslog with tag phantomjs
# for more info see http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#id152
# and/or type logger --help
console output
# execute the command and log it
exec phantomjs $SERVER -host $HOST -port $PORT | logger -s -t "phantomjs: "
```